# How to call function in destination url?

Tags: angular

I would like to call a function that is in the destination page.
Here's what I have tried:

```
<a routerLink="/{{element.url}}" (click)="logger()"> Link </a>
```

This, however calls the function inside the source page.

Comment: Why don't you call the function "logger" in ngOnInit inside destination component, which is initiated by "/" route?

Comment: Add more details, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: why don't u call logger() in constructor of destination page ?

Comment: Example: this.logger1(), this.logger2(), this.logger3(), I want to call only a specific function.